# How to install packages pyWavelets on Anaconda (python3)?

Tags: python, anaconda, pywt

How to install packages pyWavelets on Anaconda (python3)?

Using Windows 10.

Answer (score 1):

Already found the answer as I downloaded the whl file from https://pypi.python.org/pypi/PyWavelets/:

```
pip install *FILENAME*.whl
```